# Loading a pre-trained model throws ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

```
File "train.py", line 43, in <module>
    FR=FR_model()
  File "/home/arsh/Desktop/machine learning/Outlier_dataset/Face_recognition.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.model = load_model('Facenet/facenet_model.h5')
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 184, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 177, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 369, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 986, in from_config
    input_tensors, output_tensors, created_layers = reconstruct_from_config(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 2019, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 2001, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    return deserialize_keras_object(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 369, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 990, in from_config
    function = cls._parse_function_from_config(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py", line 1042, in _parse_function_from_config
    function = generic_utils.func_load(
  File "/home/arsh/.virtualenvs/conditional_slim_gan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 471, in func_load
    code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

I am trying to load a pre-trained keras model from **.h5** file using the code-
`self.model = load_model('Facenet/facenet_model.h5')`.

The code runs smoothly on google colab, however when I run it locally it throws the above error, even when my tensorflow and keras are up to date.

To reproduce the error, please navigate to **Face_recognition.py** on [my github](https://github.com/arshagarwal/outlier-experiment) repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `generic_utils.py`:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py

you'll see there is no line 471, so you seem to be running some old instance of keras and that might not be compatible with data generated with an newer (or just different) version.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if that were the reason shouldn't it also throw error on google colab.@Anthon

Comment: I don't know google colab, nor how keras stores/loads data. You don't indicate what versions of the software and Python you run on each of the platforms. If Google runs a different version than 3.8 then I certainly see a possible cause for incompatibility, but there might be other causes.

Comment: I checked the versions of python, tensorflow, keras on both the local and google colab environment, though tensorflow and keras versions were the same, my local environment used python 3.8 vs python 3.6.9 on colab, changing the python version to 3.6.9 on my local system  did the job. Thanks :) @Anthon

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble could you also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202871/model-performs-differently-for-model-fit-and-custom-training-loop).@Anthon

Comment: Sorry but I haven't done machine learning like stuff since my thesis on disambiguating word classes by statistical anlysis in the early 90's. I don't even understand the lingo that is used for ML nowadays %-)